# binding visibiility of textblock based on validataion done for textbox via routed commands

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, routed-commands

I am writing simple application,
The UI has two textboxes, for Username & Password and button to submit the information.
I wanted to use routed commands instead of buttonclick event.

Username should contain alphanumeric characters only, if user enter any other special characters, it should display a text saying invalid characters entered.
so I wanted to bind the visibility and content of that textblock based on the validation done on Username textbox field.
can any one help me on how to achieve this?

Below is code I have made but it is not working as expected. can any one help me where I am doing wrong?

Below my mainWindow.xaml

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace ExcelUtility
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel viewModelObj = new ViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void navigatePageExecuted(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SubmitUserDetails(txtUserName.Text + ";" + txtPassword);
    }

    void navigatePageCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUserName.Text))
        {
            viewModelObj.Username = txtUserName.Text;
        }
        e.CanExecute = viewModelObj.VaidUserName;        }

    private void SubmitUserDetails(string credentials)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
        prgValidate.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MainGrid.IsEnabled = false;
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(credentials);
    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        prgValidate.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        string Result = (string)e.Result;
        MessageBox.Show(Result); //Here I need to call some other functions based on return value for simplicity i have changed
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] credentials = e.Argument.ToString().Split(';');
        e.Result = viewModelObj.validateCredentials(credentials[0], credentials[1]);
    }
}
```

}

This is my xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ExcelUtility.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExcelUtility"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibleOrHidden x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:CommandsLibrary.navigatePageCommand}" Executed="navigatePageExecuted" CanExecute="navigatePageCanExecute"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,44,0,0" Name="tbUserName" Text="Username" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="136,42,0,0" Name="txtUserName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163" Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,19,0,0" Name="tbNotify" Text="{Binding Notification, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" Visibility="{Binding NotVaidUserName,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,98,0,0" Name="txtPassword" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,107,0,0" Name="tbPassword" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" />
    <Button Command="{x:Static local:CommandsLibrary.navigatePageCommand}" Content="Submit" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="172,167,0,0" Name="btnSubmit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" />
    <ProgressBar Height="24" IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="Collapsed"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,232,0,0" Name="prgValidate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" />
</Grid>
```

This is my viewModel

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows;

namespace ExcelUtility
{
  public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool _notVaidUserName;
    public bool NotVaidUserName
    {
        get { return _notVaidUserName; }
        set
        {
            _notVaidUserName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("NotVaidUserName");
        }
    }

    private string notification;
    public string Notification
    {
        get
        {
            return notification;
        }
        set
        {
            if (notification != value)
            {
                notification = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Notification");
            }
        }
    }

    private string username;
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return username;
        }
        set
        {
            if (username != value)
            {
                username = value;
                NotVaidUserName = VaidateUserName(username);
                RaisePropertyChanged("Username");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool VaidateUserName(string strUsername)
    {
        bool bValidUserName = false;            
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strUsername))
        {
            if (new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$").IsMatch(strUsername))
            {
                bValidUserName = true;
                if (strUsername.Length > 7)
                {
                    Notification = "Max allowed key length is 6";
                    bValidUserName = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Notification = "No special characters allowed";
            }
        }
        return bValidUserName;
    }

    public string validateCredentials(string Username, string Password)
    {
        return "Valid Credentials";
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

class BoolToVisibleOrHidden : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object returnvalue = new object();
        returnvalue = (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : parameter != null ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Hidden;
        return returnvalue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

}

Many thanks in advance.
Durga

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is that you have not set the data context for view. I like to set the data context in the xaml as it will give you auto-complete in VS for your binding instruction. On the root node, add the attribute

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

This will set the window itself as your data context, allowing your command to work. However, the binding expressions on the textboxes will fail. You have split your ViewModel logic over the view and the ViewModel.

I would move you code completely into the ViewModel and use

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ViewModel}"
```

as the data context. Then the only code you have in the code behind of the view would be something along the lines of

```
namespace ExcelUtility
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ViewModel viewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ViewModel ViewModel { get { return viewModel ?? (viewModel = new ViewModel()); } }
    }
}
```

Once your bindings are working, you will not have to set the UserName or Password (as you do in the navigatePageCanExecute and navigatePageExecuted methods) in the view model as the binding will set it for you.
I am not sure about your CommandsLibrary. You didn't include it in the example.

This should give you a start to figure out the rest.

I hope it helps